# Option Value is empty in Cart Section

Tags: magento2

The Mini-Cart has a problem on my Magento 2 project. When I request the following URL:

/customer/section/load/?sections=cart

I get the following Response:

```
{
   "cart":{
      "summary_count":2,
      "subtotalAmount":438,
      "subtotal":"<span class=\"price\">CHF\u00a0438.00<\/span>",
      "possible_onepage_checkout":true,
      "items":[
         {
            "product_type":"configurable",
            "options":[
               {
                  "label":"Gr\u00f6sse",
                  "value":"",
                  "option_id":659,
                  "option_value":""
               }
            ],
            "qty":2,
            "item_id":"253",
            "configure_url":"http:\/\/example.com:8000\/checkout\/cart\/configure\/id\/253\/product_id\/15828\/",
            "is_visible_in_site_visibility":true,
            "product_id":"15828",
            "product_name":"Damen, Herren Anh\u00e4ngerkette Basic",
            "product_sku":"738529101742",
            "product_url":"http:\/\/example.com:8000\/damen-herren-anh-ngerkette-basic-7612690509546-configurable.html",
            "product_has_url":true,
            "product_price":"\n    <span class=\"price-including-tax\" data-label=\"Inkl. Steuern\">\n            <span class=\"minicart-price\">\n            <span class=\"price\">CHF\u00a0219.00<\/span>        <\/span>\n\n        <\/span>\n\n",
            "product_price_value":203.35,
            "product_image":{
               "src":"http:\/\/example.com:8000\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/f485795eb4b45ff97c82d72651274f10\/7\/6\/7612690509546_2d_0001.jpg",
               "alt":"Damen, Herren Anh\u00e4ngerkette Basic",
               "width":78,
               "height":78
            },
            "canApplyMsrp":false
         }
      ],
      "extra_actions":"",
      "isGuestCheckoutAllowed":true,
      "website_id":"1",
      "subtotal_incl_tax":"<span class=\"price\">CHF\u00a0438.00<\/span>",
      "subtotal_excl_tax":"<span class=\"price\">CHF\u00a0406.69<\/span>",
      "data_id":1541069457
   }
}
```

The problem with this response is that the "Option Value" and the "value" are empty and as such are not shown in the cart. In the Backend the Option exists and has a value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might need a storeID to get that working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Log your Add to cart request parameter and verify the request has the "option id" value in url parameter.

To Log the add to cart parameter you can use this below code.

Add below code in `Magento_Checkout/Cart/Add.php`

```
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info($this->getRequest()->getParams());
```

In my case, this log file stores the below response.

```
2018-11-14T10:38:19+00:00 INFO (6): array (
  'product' => '275',

  'selected_configurable_option' => '',

  'related_product' => '',

  'form_key' => 'hECiiISxB3xEXoUW',

  'super_attribute' => 
  array (

    141 => '168',

    93 => '60',
  ),
  'qty' => '1',
  'product_page' => 'true',
)
```

Please verify that, please check the **super_attribute** array, in my case **option_id** is in the cart resonse.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to put a configurable item in your cart that does not have options selected if the option value is not in the array being returned then you had an error while adding to cart you can look in the `quote_item_option` table to see if the quote item has the options stored.